# Как использовать requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, анимация

Я изучаю requestAnimationFrame и запускать функцию отрисовки у меня получается. Я не понимаю, как управлять тем, на какой стадии находится отрисованный элемент.
Я написал, что шарик идёт вниз на 100px за секунду. Но при достижении 100px при запуске следующей анимации, я хотел бы, чтобы запустилась другая анимация, при которой шарик шёл бы обратно.
Как в хорошем коде управляет анимацией в requestAnimationFrame?

```js
var el = document.getElementById("first");
var elem = document.getElementById("second");

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

 let start = performance.now();

 requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
  let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
  if (timeFraction > 1) {
   timeFraction = 1;
  }
  let progress = timing(timeFraction);
  draw(progress);
  if (timeFraction < 1) {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
 });
}

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
 animate({
        duration: 1000,
        timing: function(timeFraction) {
          return timeFraction;
        },
        draw: function(progress) {
         if (elem.style.top == (100 + 'px') || num == 1) {
          var num = 1;
          elem.style.top = progress * 0 + 'px';
         } else {
          elem.style.top = progress * 100 + 'px';
         }
         
        }
     });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#first, #second {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: red;
}

#second {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: хорошая анимация - это чистая функция от времени, в каждом кадре Вы однозначно знаете сколько прошло времени и соответственно однозначно можете определить где должен находится объект...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ покажите, пожалуйста, пример, я не понимаю

Comment: Можете так же посмотреть мой codepen, я в основном только анимацию туда и складываю https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pens/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошая анимация - это чистая функция от времени, в каждом кадре Вы однозначно знаете сколько прошло времени и соответственно однозначно можете определить где должен находится объект...

```js
animation.innerHTML = Array(30).fill(0).map((e, i) => {
  return `<div style='background-color:hsl(${i*12},66%,66%)'></div>`;
}).join('');

let circles = document.querySelectorAll('#animation div');

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(t)  {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  circles.forEach((c,i) => {
    c.style.top = 55 + 50*(Math.sin(t/300-i*100)) + "px";
    c.style.transform = `scale(${0.7+Math.sin(t/300-i*33)*0.3})`;
    c.style.left = i*21+5 + Math.cos(t/255-i)*5 + "px";
  })  
}
```

```css
#animation div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=animation><div>
```

Comment: А тут нету функции от времени, вы не можете управлять временем, да?

Comment: А, всё, я увидел t параметрах функции draw, и что она используется в функции